# É possível pedir um arquivo em específico para o user

Tags: java, android

Quero pegar um arquivo em especial do usuário. Tem como colocar o nome desse arquivo como `type` na `Intent`? Para uma imagem por exemplo, se usa:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
intent.setType("image/*") 
startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
```

É possível definir o nome do arquivo que quero no `setType()` pra aparecer apenas ele e os diretórios? O arquivo é um "backup" do banco de dados chamado "tobuy.db".

Comment: Quer validar pelo mime ou pela extensão? Se for pelo mime é só trocar a string.

Comment: @LINQ, mas no caso eu trocaria a string para que? vi que pdf por exemplo, é usado "application/pdf", o que eu poderia usar como string para procurar só o arquivo "tobuy.db" (ou com a extensão .db)?

Comment: eu não entendo bem como funcionam as coisas no Android. Me diga: existe algum arquivo XML (ou similar) atrelado ao arquivo que contém o código da sua pergunta?

Comment: @LINQ, não, é apenas esse código mesmo, ele basicamente chama a Intent.ACTION_PICK e apps que tenham activitys que recebam essa Intent (ou algo assim) vão aparecer pra serem escolhidos (como o manage file ou a galeria), aí eu teria que passar o setType como argumento pra ele saber o que mostrar (como apenas imagens, por exemplo), ai queria que deixasse escolher apenas arquivos com certo nome, mas não sei se isso é possível

Comment: usa o autocomplete e tenta procurar por algum método chamado setPath, setPathPattern ou similares

Comment: já procurei, vi na documentação do android e tem uma lista de vários tipos de arquivos e como é o mime dele, mas parece que são pra coisas pré-definidas pelo gerenciador de arquivos, pelo que vi não tem como você "criar um", mas vai que há e alguém me responda né ashuahsuas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256537/android-intent-filter-for-custom-file-extension ???

Comment: @IsraelMerljak, na verdade eu queria que o File Manager do Android (ou a activity de qlqr app que receba essa intent) mostrasse apenas arquivos com aquela extensão ou nome, é possível ou terei que ver se encontro uma lib em especial? (ou vai ver nem existe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, mas não foi através de MIME type e nem de gerenciadores padrões, baixei a biblioteca aFileDialog (https://github.com/jfmdev/aFileDialog) e nela você pode mandar o tipo de extensão que você quer que seja mostrado, também há como escolher uma pasta ao invés de um arquivo, etc. O único mal da biblioteca é que o design está meio feiozinho, mas como é código aberto então você pode modificar.